# Mac terminal bash profile cannot add another path after downloading Anacoda

Tags: mysql, macos

I started to learn MySQL recently and I have a 2015 MacBook Air. After installing MySQL server, I ran `pip install MySQL-connector-python`.

Everything worked perfectly fine but my terminal cannot find mysql command line.

I did a lot of reseach on internet and I figured out the reason is my terminal environment hasn't located `mysql`, so I tried to add the `bash_profile` but it doesn't work.

I began to think that maybe I got the wrong path of mysql, so I did another batch of searches on how to get the right path of mac folders. And it's still not working.

Finally, I typed `export path: path....(regular MySQL path)`, and then I use the mysql command, and the terminal could find it!

Now, I can use MySQL but each time I have to type `export (MySQL path)`.

I doubt the reason why I cannot add a valid `bash_profile` path is that I have an anaconda in my computer and there is a long path belonging to anaconda inside my bash_profile.

Here is what my bash_profile looks like and I hope someone who knows Linux can help me out. I just want to know why and if you want to share more, you are so welcome!

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/Users/fresh/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/fresh/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/fresh/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/Users/fresh/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<

export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

As you can see, I already added the path, but my terminal just cannot find mysql.

Side Note: My computer is really old but in MacOS 11.8 big sur, so that could be a possible reason but I m just not knowing enough to be sure.

Comment: I am really sorry that I forgot the space is merged in the stack after I posted it. This makes my question looks really long and messy, I am soooooo sorry.....

Comment: A couple of things.  In `Big Sur` the default shell is `zsh`, so setting anything in `.bash_profile` won't make a difference unless you explicitly changed your default shell in User management or made your zsh load bash by default.  Secondly, the syntax `export path: path....(regular MySQL path)` is plain wrong, I'd be surprised it that worked for either bash or zsh.

Comment: Thank you tink! I used export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin in my terminal. I think that's the right syntax. Sorry I typed the wrong syntax in my question. Now I know that I need to do something with my zsh... Thank you so much cause now a lot of terminal/macOS-related answers are a bit old, it's still the solution for the old mac system, not big sur... I would search for big sur solution next time I got problems...

Comment: glad to have set you on the right path.